# Laravel 4 - Too much logic in my view template?

Tags: php, laravel

i created a search functionality within my Laravel project - the user can search for teamnames or usernames - the result is created and returned like this:

```
    $teams_obj = Team::where('teamname', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('searchterm').'%')->get();
    $persons_obj = User::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('searchterm').'%')->orWhere('vorname', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('searchterm').'%')->get();

    return View::make("team.search-content", array('resp' => 'resultlist', 'teams_obj' => $teams_obj, 'persons_obj' => $persons_obj))->with('user', User::find(Auth::user()->id));
```

Now its getting a little more complicated. I have a database table "relation" which stores if a user is a member of a team via an entry containing user_id and team_id. Laravel knows this relation.

If the search result is displayed within the view, i have to make a distinction if the current user is already a member in the respective team which is displayed in the current row. If the user is already a member within the team he should not be able to apply, otherwise he should have the option to apply.

I solved it with this:

```
                @foreach($teams_obj as $team_obj)
                    <li data-teamid="{{ $team_obj->id }}">                      
                    <span>{{ $team_obj->teamname }}</span>
                    <?php
                    $data = ['user_id' => $user->id, 'team_id' => $team_obj->id];
                    $res = $team_obj->whereHas('Relation', function($q) use ($data) {
                        $q->where('team_id', '=', $data['team_id']);
                        $q->where('user_id', '=', $data['user_id']);
                    })->get();
                    if (count($res) == 0) {
                    echo'apply fct available';
                    }                                               
                    ?>
                    </li>
                @endforeach
```

I fetch the relation and check if the relation of team_id and user_id is existent. But i have a strange feeling doing this within my view template. What do you think? How can i improve this?

Additionally i think it is strange that i have to make $q->where('team_id'), as I already do $team_obj-> ... but otherwise it is not working correctly.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any need to show teams that your user cannot apply ? if not you can simply modify your code to get teams that your user is not a member. If you need you can do some checkup in the controller in order to get that information.

I suggest making a foreach for the every team and checking if they have relationship with the user. You can set an attribute in a team to check in the view.

Controller:

```
 foreach($teams_obj as $team_obj){
   $res = $team_obj->whereHas('Relation', function($q) use ($data) {
                    $q->where('team_id', '=', $data['team_id']);
                    $q->where('user_id', '=', $data['user_id']);
                })->get();
   if(count($res) == 0)
     $team_obj->isApplyableByUser = true;
   else
     $team_obj->isApplyableByUser = false;

   // You can do the same code above in one line, but it's not that compreensive
   $team_obj->isApplyableByUser = count($res) == 0;
}
```

View:

```
if($team_obj->isApplyableByUser) echo'apply fct available';
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, too much logic for a view (in terms of best practices)

Do you have relationships set up for these?  Assuming `Team` `hasMany('User')`... Why not just eager load your `User` models?

```
$teams = Team::with(['users' => function($query){
    $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('searchterm').'%')
        ->orWhere('vorname', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('searchterm').'%')
    }])where('teamname', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('searchterm').'%')
    ->get();

return View::make('your.view', ['teams' => $teams]);
```

// And in your view.

```
@foreach($teams as $team)
    <li data-teamid="{{ $team->id }}">                      
    <span>{{ $team->teamname }}</span>
    @if(!$team->users->count())
        apply fct available
    @endif
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: My relationships are stored within the table "relations". Therefore in User and Team i have: hasMany('Relation'); In Relation i've got: belongsTo('User'); and belongsTo('Team');